# Limit Point vs Boundary Point

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Kosniowski's book on algebraic topology, and I have a question about how he defines limit points. He says that for a subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$, the limit points of $Y$ are precisely the points in $\overline{Y}$ that are not in $Y$. This seems to conflict with my previous understanding of a limit point as a point that can be in $Y$ but might not be. Would Kosniowski's definition of a limit point be consistent with the term, "boundary point". If so, is it common to see this term defined differently by different authors (like neighborhoods)?

Comment: No, it would not be consistent with the usual definition of boundary point. A closed set contains its boundary, for example.

Comment: I see. Then I'm very confused as to what Kosniowski's definition is consistent with. For the set $A=(0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$, every point in $[0,1]$ is a limit point of $A$ in the "usual" sense, but in Kosniowski's def., only the point $0$ would be a limit point of $A$

Comment: Yep. I have no idea what the intention and idea behind it may be.